# Theorem 2.3 from Functions of One Complex Variable by Conway

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understand the proof of theorem 2.3 from Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable and it states:

An open set $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ is connected iff for any two points a, b in G there is a polygon from a to b lying entirely inside $G$.

First, he proves that if for any two points a, b in G there is a polygon from a to b lying entirely inside G, then $G$ is connected.

He assumes that for any two points a, b in G there is a polygon P from a to b lying entirely inside G and that G is not connected and $G=A\cup B$, where $A,B$ are non-empty, disjoint and open and closed. In the proof, he states that there exists a segment in the polygon P such that it has one point in A and another in B. And writes:

> "So, we can assume that P=[a,b].Let S=$\{s \in [0,1]:sb+(1-s)a \in
> > A\}$ and let T=$\{t \in [0,1]:tb+(1-t)a \in A\}$....$S\cup T=[0,1]$ ". 
>   So, it appears that $[a,b]$ should be in G itself.

I don't fully understand how one can make this assumption. The following figure seems to contradict this and point $x$ lies outside the set G but it is in $[a,b]$.

I am sure I am making a mistake but I can't find it. Should I add more details to the question?

All I am trying to make is that when Conway assumes that $P=[a,b]$ and defines S and T, then he assumes that $[a,b]$ lies completely in G while the image I have drawn seems to contradict that.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $\Bbb C$ has the property that every point has a *convex* neighborhood, to wit, a ball. The ball has the property every pair of points can be joined by a straight line. That is $\Bbb C$ is "locally polygonally connected". Thus we expect that *open* sets share a weakened version of this.

Now suppose you have an open set $G$, and you fix any point in $G$; call it $z$. Consider the set $G_1$ of points $w\in G$ that *can* be joined to $z$ by a polygonal path, take $G_2=G\smallsetminus G_1$. If we show that $G_1$ is open and closed, we can deduce $G_1=G$ when $G$ is connected, since $z\in G_1$ forces $G_2=\varnothing$.

If $w\in G_1$, say $\gamma$ is a polygonal path in $G$ from $z$ to $w$. Since $G$ is open, we can take a ball $B$ contained in $G$ that contains $w$. But since $B$ is convex, every point of $B$ can be joined to $w$ by a straight line, and by gluing with $\gamma$ we get a poligonal path to $z$. Hence $B\subseteq G_1$ and $G_1$ is open. Now suppose $w\notin G_1$. Again, there is a ball $B\subseteq G$ that contains $w$. But then $B$ is disjoint from $G_1$: every point of $B$ can be joined to $w$ by a straight line, so if we could join a point of $B$ to $z$ we could again glue and join $z$ to $w$, but $w$ is *not* in $G_1$. It follows that $B\cap G_1=\varnothing$. Hence $G_1$ is both open and closed.

Note we simply used balls are convex.

Comment: I think you proved that if G satisfies those properties, then G is connected. I am trying to prove the other way round.

Comment: @user96343 I proved what you asked. Read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The polygon does have to be a straight line segment.  It could be made up from to connected line segments. Suppose you take a point $c$ in the interior of the domain. Say it is on the boundary of $A$ and $B$.  Then take the line segment form $a$ to $c$ in conjunction with the line segment from $c$ to $b$.

Comment: No, I mean $[a,b]$ has been defined to be the line-segment joining $a$ and $b$.